# Is there a grace period to post an answer to a question after it is closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, answers

[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/662390/305718) has been published 23 minutes ago, while the question was closed 25 minutes ago, *at the moment*. Also [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/661486/305718) was published a minute after closing the question (another).

So how does this happen? It is something like answering closed questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, under certain technical circumstances it can happen that an answer is posted up to 4 hours after closure. See [this meta.SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/263383) for more information.